# How to flatten deep dictionary; surrounding any child dictionary keys with square brackets

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Maybe this is called something specifically - I just don't know.
If you have some data in a dictionary like so:

```py
data1 = {
  "first": {"a":24,
            "b": {"green": {"look": 3,
                            "out": "Nope"},
                  "apple": True}},
  "third": {"x": {"word": 8}, "y": -1, "z": 26},
  "fifth": {"ae": [0, None, 2.0, 3.0],
            "e": None}
}
```

Is there some function from some module that does this (or some other tool)?

```py
data2 = {
  "first[a]": 24,
  "first[b][green][look]": 3,
  "first[b][green][out]": "Nope",
  "first[b][apple]": True,
  "third[x][word]": 8,
  "third[y]": -1,
  "third[z]": 26,
  "fifth[ae][0]": 0,
  "fifth[ae][1]": None,
  "fifth[ae][2]": 2.0,
  "fifth[ae][3]": 3.0,
  "fifth[e]": None
}
```

I made a function to get the flattened keys/values like:

```py
def get_deep_dict_keys_gen(data, sep="."):
  if isinstance(data, list): iter = map(lambda t: (str(t[0]), t[1]), enumerate(data))
  elif isinstance(data, dict): iter = data.items()
  else: iter = []
  for k, v in iter:
    if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list):
      yield from [k + sep + x for x in get_deep_dict_keys_gen(v, sep=sep)]
    else:
      yield k

# I can make the flatten dictionary again using a function _g(data, path), that gets the deep path value.

{x: _g(data1, x) for x in util.get_deep_dict_keys_gen(data1)}

# Which makes:

{
  'fifth.ae.0': 0,
  'fifth.ae.1': None,
  'fifth.ae.2': 2.0,
  'fifth.ae.3': 3.0,
  'fifth.e': None,
  'first.a': 24,
  'first.b.apple': True,
  'first.b.green.look': 3,
  'first.b.green.out': 'Nope',
  'third.x.word': 8,
  'third.y': -1,
  'third.z': 26
}
```

I just don't know how to recursively get the keys w/ the data values. Maybe there is some tool that does this; I see it done in the browser with website interactions. Taking some json on a page - and making a post request in the layout of `data2`.

Edit: Thanks for the help, Arun Augustine.

Comment: I don't understand. The output of your function is nearly identical to `data2`. The only difference I see is the format of the keys, which could easily be transformed either with modifications to your function, or another pass over its output. Can you elaborate on this: "I just don't know how to recursively get the keys w/ the data values."? Are you trying to produce keys given a specific value?

Comment: I've naively tried to modify this function - but am running into this problem where I can't add the the sub-keys with brackets around them to the top-level key (without brackets) while doing this recursively.

Comment: Since you already have a working function, perhaps just create another dict with all the keys formatted base on the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
from itertools import chain, starmap


def flatten_dict(dictionary):
    """Flatten a nested dictionary structure"""

    def unpack(parent_key, parent_value):
        """Unpack one level of nesting in a dictionary"""
        try:
            items = parent_value.items()
        except AttributeError:
            # parent_value was not a dict, no need to flatten
            yield (parent_key, parent_value)
        else:
            for key, value in items:
                if type(value) == list:
                    for k, v in enumerate(value):
                        yield (parent_key + '[' + key + ']' + '['+str(k)+']', v)
                else:
                    yield (parent_key + '['+key+']', value)
    while True:
        # Keep unpacking the dictionary until all value's are not dictionary's
        dictionary = dict(chain.from_iterable(starmap(unpack, dictionary.items())))
        if not any(isinstance(value, dict) for value in dictionary.values()):
            break
    return dictionary

# Input Dict
input_dict = {
"first": {"a": 24,
          "b": {"green": {"look": 3,
                          "out": "Nope"},
                "apple": True}},
"third": {"x": {"word": 8}, "y": -1, "z": 26},
"fifth": {"ae": [0, None, 2.0, 3.0],
          "e": None}
}  

print(flatten_dict(input_dict))
```

OutPut:

```
{
'first[a]': 24,
'first[b][green][look]': 3,
'first[b][green][out]': 'Nope',
'first[b][apple]': True,
'third[x][word]': 8,
'third[y]': -1,
'third[z]': 26,
'fifth[ae][0]': 0,
'fifth[ae][1]': None,
'fifth[ae][2]': 2.0,
'fifth[ae][3]': 3.0,
'fifth[e]': None
```

}

Comment: That is awesome how it's done, you're awesome - I had to step through it to get the gist of the unpacking. That while loop & `dictionary = dict(chain.from_iterable(starmap(unpack, dictionary.items())))` was the special sauce.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption in this below data is list element does not contains either `dict` or `list`.

```
data1 = {
  "first": {"a":24,
            "b": {"green": {"look": 3,
                            "out": "Nope"},
                  "apple": True}},
  "third": {"x": {"word": 8}, "y":-1, "z": 26},
  "fifth": {"ae": [0, None, 2.0, 3.0],
            "e": None}
}
```

`add_dict` method is generator and responsible for looping over each key and its value. Given value is dictionary object, the method will call itself.

```
def add_dict(_dict):
    for key, value in _dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for indexof, value in add_dict(value):
                yield '[{0}]'.format(key) + indexof, value
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for indexof, value in add_list(value): 
                yield '[{0}]'.format(key) + indexof, value
        else:
            yield '[{0}]'.format(key), value
```

`add_list` method is generator. It's element does not contains either `dict` or `list` and so it looks as simple.

```
def add_list(_list):
    for index, elem in enumerate(_list):
        yield '[{0}]'.format(index), elem
```

`flatten` is a main method and generator. It's element contains `dict` only and so it looks as simple.

```
def flatten(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        for indexof, value in add_dict(value):
            yield '{0}'.format(key) + indexof, value


print(dict(flatten(data1)))
```

Output of above execution

```
{'fifth[ae][0]': 0,
 'fifth[ae][1]': None,
 'fifth[ae][2]': 2.0,
 'fifth[ae][3]': 3.0,
 'fifth[e]': None,
 'first[a]': 24,
 'first[b][apple]': True,
 'first[b][green][look]': 3,
 'first[b][green][out]': 'Nope',
 'third[x][word]': 8,
 'third[y]': -1,
 'third[z]': 26}
```